# Unable to use SDK for Zebra Scanner model MC33

Tags: c#, android, sdk, barcode-scanner, zebra-printers

I'm developing a windows application with using scanner Zebra MC33.
There is SDK pack which is described here: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/scanner-sdk-for-android.html

But my model MC33 is not in a list of approved devices. And test desktop app (supply in pack with SDK) does not detect my device.

Can somebody recommed what to do and if Zebra inc. plan to release SDK for my device (MC33) as well?

UPDATE: during debug my app catch answer code

```
112 = "ERROR_DEVICE_UNAVAILABLE" = " Required device is unavailable"
```

Comment: Have you tried asking Zebra?

Comment: I just have some other questions ... "windows application ?" do you mean a xamarin application ?

Comment: Hi @HeadJ.E.M. , not Xamarin, but automated test with Attium and Selenium drivers. Actually my main aim is perform trigger press like human do pressing trigger button for scanning barcode.

Comment: The ZEBRA MC33 series is a mobile computer, some models with a built-in scanner, not a scanner. It seems that you have presented an SDK for a single function scanner device. What you need for the ZEBRA MC33 series is the material on this page. [MC3300 MOBILE COMPUTER SUPPORT](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/mobile-computers/handheld/mc3300.html)

Comment: See following article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-device-support

Comment: Not sure why a very similar question was recently asked and deleted : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60360752/uwp-xaml-c-sharp-unsupported-magstripe-recognition-on-swipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for Zebra and would concur with the comments below your question.  The SDK you are using is designed for our range of handheld rugged scanners but the MC33 is considered a Mobile Computer and uses a different SDK.

I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve by `I'm developing a windows application with using scanner Zebra MC33`.  That device runs Android so if you want to send scan data to an application running on Windows you will first need to capture those scans on the device and then send them (through IP or BT for example) to your Windows desktop app.  There are a few ways to do this (https://techdocs.zebra.com/help/) is a good entry point - you could use DataWedge to send the data over IP or you could write an Android app to send the data over a BT socket.  There is a Xamarin SDK for C# development on the device that is popular with Windows developers but I don't think you mean that.

Comment: Thank you Darryn, late I understood my confusion with rugged scaners and mobile computers. Also @kunif wrote correct comment.
My "windows application" is tests scenario by using Appium and Selenium. And during the scenario I need emulate scanning of a barcode.